# Can not install the app on Windows

Tags: windows, cordova, win-universal-app

While it builds fine (there are warnings, but no errors), I cannot install a Cordova app on Windows (Windows 10) and the other dev of the project tried to do it and ran into the exact same error messages. Now, I tried googling for info, but I couldn't find anything of use, so I'm posting here.

So here's the cmd output I get from running "cordova build windows": http://pastebin.com/Fmtw9d7Z

It looks like it builds successfully, although there are warnings.
Then I run "cordova run windows" and this is what I get: http://pastebin.com/CYA7RwZH

As it suggested, I tried running "Get-AppxLog" and this is the output that I got from that: http://pastebin.com/Axwea7Ft

I've tried rebuilding/rerunning multiple times and at one point I actually did find an older version of the app installed (in Start -> All Apps) and I uninstalled it manually (Right Click -> Uninstall), but it doesn't look like it helped or did anything.

Comment: Did you check if your device is set to be in developper mode?
Under your windows start menu -> Settings->updates and sécurity -> for developpers

Comment: Yes, developer mode is turned on.